# how do i update the form's state when a prop is changed

Tags: reactjs

When clicking the edit button,it needs to set a value of state on the    component,i need a way to update the form's state when the  formProduct  prop is changed.
[here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/sweet-mestorf-vs8fb)

Comment: You could lift the events `onEdit` or `onDelete` to the component that is containing the state and handle the state change there - requires passing down the props. Or you could use `React.context` like in the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-morning-vrrjl) and I think that's easier. I'll create a small example of the props-drilling in a minute.

Comment: you're welcome. Great to hear that it is working. Are you using `React.context` now? Maybe I'll add a short answer to explain it.

Comment: @AWolf yes please if you could explain more about it idd appreciate